# Spring boot org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode

Tags: java, spring-boot, repository

I'm trying to start a spring boot service and I got this error:

The type org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Any idea how I can resolve it?

This is the class where eclipse says that is the problem:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = { "es.eci.amv.repository.oracleCentral" })
public class OracleCentralConfig {

    @Bean(name = "oracleCentralDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.oracle-central.datasource")
    public DataSource oracleCentralDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("oracleCentralDataSource") DataSource oracleCentralDataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(oracleCentralDataSource)
                .packages("es.eci.amv.model.oracleCentral")
                .persistenceUnit("oracle-central")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "oracleCentralTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oracleCentralTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(oracleCentralEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the version of org.springframework.data to the Spring boot version.